# Getting rid of the form validation error bubble in Panopoly

Tags: theming, forms, distributions

In Panopoly, errors that display with `form_set_error()` do not display in a block at the top of the page the way they normally do in Drupal. Instead they display in a floating popup that looks like a speech bubble.

How do I get rid of this bubble? It sounds silly but I can't figure out how to get rid of it and make it use the normal Drupal styling for validation errors.